# convert all the variables from unicode to string in python at single instance by adding some headers

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode-string

I have many variables which has unicode values in python file as below :

```
var1 = u'urname'
var2 = u'myname'
var3 = u'name'
```

I can convert from unicode to string all the variables as:

```
var1 = str(var1)
var2 = str(var2)
var3 = str(var3)
```

But I want to know can we convert all the variables from unicode to string at single instance?

Comment: Why do you have so many separate variables in the first place? Why not use a list or a dictionary? That would make encoding all those strings to bytes much easier.

Comment: Also, why do you need to convert to byte strings? If you are using `str()`, then the Unicode strings only contain ASCII codepoints so you can safely use these unicode strings everywhere a string is expected and Python auto-encodes for you anyway.

Comment: All the variables are not related to each other , just as pseudo I havv given here.

Comment: Then encode each of those as needed.